# Modify data in xml files using Golang

Tags: arrays, xml, string, go

I  want to change the lastModifiedBy field from Tom Hanks to Jerry Garcia. I used this repo: https://github.com/clbanning/mxj/blob/master/xml.go to parse the xml bytes into a map. However, some fields were left out.

What's an easy way to change that field and only that field? There are hundreds of these files so I need to do it programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties 
 xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core- 
 properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
 xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
 xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><dc:title></dc:title> 
<dc:subject></dc:subject><dc:creator>John Kerry</dc:creator> 
<cp:keywords></cp:keywords><dc:description></dc:description> 
<cp:lastModifiedBy>TomHanks</cp:lastModifiedBy><cp:revision>6</cp:revision> 
<dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-02- 
20T18:08:00Z</dcterms:created><dcterms:modified 
xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-04-24T19:43:00Z</dcterms:modified> 
</cp:coreProperties>
```

Comment: I suspect you are going to have some difficulty re-creating all the namespacing and other attributes back in the recreated xml. In other words, you could likely parse this properly and come up with 'TomHanks' somewhere, but when you went to write it back as xml, you would lose some information in the document.

Is go the proper tool for this job? Would you be better off with something like `sed` or `perl` and treat it like a text replacement perhaps?

Comment: That's what I'm starting to think... big headache here haha because I've got a lot of go code behind this with opening files and what not. needs to run on a Windows platform so wasn't sure if bash would run as an executable in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just this then (easiest thing that works) then after the replace do the xml parsing? Not sure if the TomHanks => Jerry Garcia thing is really always the same thing, or you have to parameterize this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)


var xmlRaw = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties 
 xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core- 
 properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
 xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
 xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><dc:title></dc:title> 
<dc:subject></dc:subject><dc:creator>John Kerry</dc:creator> 
<cp:keywords></cp:keywords><dc:description></dc:description> 
<cp:lastModifiedBy>TomHanks</cp:lastModifiedBy><cp:revision>6</cp:revision> 
<dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-02- 
20T18:08:00Z</dcterms:created><dcterms:modified 
xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-04-24T19:43:00Z</dcterms:modified> 
</cp:coreProperties>`

type decoder struct {

}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(xmlRaw, "TomHanks", "Jerry Garcia", 1))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/viTLElQxesM

this demonstrates the problem I was describing:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var xmlRaw = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties 
 xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core- 
 properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
 xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
 xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><dc:title></dc:title> 
<dc:subject></dc:subject><dc:creator>John Kerry</dc:creator> 
<cp:keywords></cp:keywords><dc:description></dc:description> 
<cp:lastModifiedBy>TomHanks</cp:lastModifiedBy><cp:revision>6</cp:revision> 
<dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-02- 
20T18:08:00Z</dcterms:created><dcterms:modified 
xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-04-24T19:43:00Z</dcterms:modified> 
</cp:coreProperties>`)

type decoder struct {
    Keywords       string `xml:"keywords"`
    LastModifiedBy string `xml:"lastModifiedBy"`
    //.. more xml
}

func main() {
    d := decoder{}
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(xmlRaw, &d); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d.LastModifiedBy)
    d.LastModifiedBy = "Jerry Garcia"
    bytes, err := xml.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/aYa01_3UE5e

Output:

```
TomHanks

<decoder><keywords></keywords><lastModifiedBy>Jerry Garcia</lastModifiedBy></decoder>
```

Comment: Not able to get the cp:coreProperties because go doesn't like the colon between cp and coreProperties. I'm trying to use string manipulation to get the data. Not sure if best method but I'll see what happens.

Comment: @Gofurther: you don't reference an element name with the colon, that's the separator between the namespace prefix and the actual name.

Answer (score -4):

```
<cp:lastModifiedBy>JerryGarcia</cp:lastModifiedBy><cp:revision>6</cp:revision>
```

Delete TomHanks and write JerryGarcia

Comment: It's gotta be done on like 50,000 files unfortunately

Comment: Use a for loop ;)

Comment: But how would I access that field?

Comment: Create a variable that gets element by tag name cp:lastModifiedBy and use it in the for loop. Then change that variable's value inside the for loop.

Comment: Yeah that'd be nice. Not sure how to go about getting that tag name though. Doesn't seem to be anything inside Go's xml package. Do you have any idea? Much appreciated.

Comment: @Gofurther: I'm not sure what you mean about not being anything in go's xml package. You can decode into structures, or iterate over the decoder one token at a time. The only issue might be that encoder doesn't supporting encoding back with the same namespace prefixes, and will have an `xmlns` attr for each tag.